# Hydrating PHP objects from json using JMS Serializer

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm looking for a way to hydrate PHP objects from json data using JMS Serializer.

I know the deserialize method is the answer but the difficulty is that I want to map fields using different attribute names.

Example:
I have a json object representing my user :

```
{"Id": 1, "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe"}
```

I have a PHP class for my user :

```
<?php

namespace Model;

class User
{
    private $id;

    private $firstName;

    private $lastName;
}
```

As you see, the case doesn't match, so I have an error saying attribute $Id doesn't exist, but the fact is I don't want to define this attribute because I want to map it another way.

Extensivly, I would like in some cases to match {"numeroTelephone": "0123456789"} with a property $phoneNumber, so I would like to use a very flexible way.

I tried to use SerializedName but it doesn't seem to work the way I would.
I tried to customize the deserialization method but I'm kind of stucked.

[EDIT]
I was using SerializedName with annotation, but it looks like it's disabled when you override the default behavior in Symfony configuration (parameters.jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy) but I finally made it work thanks to https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/334#issuecomment-190651143.
But it didn't help me because the SerializedName annotation handles both serialization and deserialization in the same way and I want different behaviors.

For example, I want to hydrate an object property `id` with a json string `{"Id": 1}` and then serialize it as `{"id": 1}`. I'm wondering if there is a way to handle the deserialization and the serialization in different ways. I found maybe a way with http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#handlercallback but I couldn't be able to use it as I wanted.

Thanks for the answer :)

Guillaume

Comment: Any idea anyone or did I stump everyone ? :)

Comment: Can you please share how did you try to use SerializedName?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post